# Power of Augmentation Ideals of Group Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

Let $R[G]$ be a group ring and $w$ be an augmentation ideal of $R[G]$.
What is meant by the power of augmentation ideal of $R[G]$, $w^n$?
I couldn't find a formal definition in any literature.
Is it just simply mean that
$w^n=\{g^n|g\in w\}$?

Comment: The augmentation ideal $I$ is generated by $g-1$ for $g\in G$; its $n$-th power is its $n$-th power as an ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be the same as the definition of the power of any ideal, that is:

$I^n=\left \{\sum_{k=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^n i_{jk} \mid i_{jk}\in I, m \in \mathbb N\right\}$